# initializing buttons on beaglebone black

Tags: c, embedded, gpio, file-descriptor, beagleboneblack

I have code to initialize **GPIO** and read the button state value from a file descriptor. I only have 3 buttons.The code is very simple. first I initialize 3 gpio and configure them to output. then I open 3 file descriptors (1 for each button) and then read the value. and this happens in an endless loop. When you press one button, the voltage changes on all three. Everything works correctly for one button. You can see a screenshot of dsview logic analyzer. What could be the reason

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define GPIO_BUTTON_IN 66
#define GPIO_BUTTON_OUT 67
#define GPIO_BUTTON_NEW 68

int GPIO_init(int pinNumber, const char *direction);
int GPIO_read(int pinNumber);
int GPIO_open(int pinNumber);
void GPIO_close(int gpio_fd);

int GPIO_init(int pinNumber, const char *direction)
{
    char buffer[50];
    char direction_path[50];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d", pinNumber);

    // Check if the GPIO folder already exists
    if (access(buffer, F_OK) != 0)
    {
        // If it doesn't exist, create the GPIO folder
        snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "echo %d > /sys/class/gpio/export", pinNumber);
        system(buffer);
    }

    snprintf(direction_path, sizeof(direction_path), "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/direction", pinNumber);
    printf("direction_path = %s\n\r", direction_path);
    int gpio_fd = open(direction_path, O_WRONLY);
    if (gpio_fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Error opening GPIO direction");
        return 0;
    }

    // Set the GPIO direction
    write(gpio_fd, direction, strlen(direction));
    close(gpio_fd);

    printf("GPIO direction set to %s for pin %d\n", direction, pinNumber);

    return 1;
}

int GPIO_read(int gpio_fd)
{
    char value;
    int bytesRead = read(gpio_fd, &value, 1);
    if (bytesRead == -1)
    {
        perror("Error reading GPIO value");
        return -1;
    }
    return (value == '1') ? 1 : 0;
}
int GPIO_open(int pinNumber)
{
    char buffer[50];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "/sys/class/gpio/gpio%d/value", pinNumber);
    int fd = open(buffer, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        perror("Error opening GPIO value file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return fd;
}

void GPIO_close(int gpio_fd)
{
    close(gpio_fd);
}
int main()
{
    if (GPIO_init(GPIO_BUTTON_IN, "in") != 1 || GPIO_init(GPIO_BUTTON_OUT, "in") != 1 || GPIO_init(GPIO_BUTTON_NEW, "in") != 1)
    {
        perror("GPIO initialization failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("GPIO initialization successful!\n");

    while (1)
    {
        int button_fd_in = GPIO_open(GPIO_BUTTON_IN);
        int button_fd_out = GPIO_open(GPIO_BUTTON_OUT);
        int button_fd_new = GPIO_open(GPIO_BUTTON_NEW);
        if (button_fd_in == -1 || button_fd_out == -1 || button_fd_new == -1)
        {
            perror("Error opening GPIO value file");
            break;
        }
        int button_state_in=GPIO_read(button_fd_in);
        int button_state_out=GPIO_read(button_fd_out);
        int button_state_new=GPIO_read(button_fd_new);

        if (!button_state_in)
        {
            printf("Button IN press\n");
        }
        if (!button_state_out) 
        {
            printf("Button OUT press\n");
        }
        if (!button_state_new) 
        {
            printf("Button NEW press\n");
        }
        GPIO_close(button_fd_in);
        GPIO_close(button_fd_out);
        GPIO_close(button_fd_new);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why open and close all the time in the loop? Why not open once first?

Comment: On an unrelated note: When you have something like `return (value == '1') ? 1 : 0;`, it's really equivalent to `return value == '1';`

Comment: Oh, and how are these buttons wired to your system? Perhaps there's short-circuit or some cross-connection in the wiring so all buttons are connected to all three GPIO?

Comment: @Some programmer dude
I would like to open and close only once, but if I do this, the value in the file register does not change, while when I call cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio66/value the value is correct.

Comment: @Some programmer dude  since value is a character and I want to return the integer

Comment: The result of a comparison like `value == '1'` is a `bool` value, which can be implicitly converted to the `int` value `1` (if it's true) or `0` (if it's false). You can return that directly, without any conditional expression.

Comment: "_I initialize 3 gpio and configure them to *output*_" - did you mean _input_?  If pressing a button causes the level on all 3 _inputs_ to change, how is that a software problem?  Does that happen even when this code _is not_ running?  In which case it is a hardware issue.

Comment: Side note: Use `gpio-keys` kernel driver and respective Device Tree for the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

I added a resistor for each button and everything worked. If someone can explain to me why, I will be glad. thanks everyone

Comment: Depending on your circuit topology, and the value of the resistor, it would have provided isolation between the signal from the momentarily pushed button and the other two.

Comment: If you want an answer to that, then you should ask on https://electronics.stackexchange.com

Comment: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/buttons_and_switches/ (nevermind that it is raspberry pi, the principles of switch input hardware are the same for any processor).

Comment: In series or as a pull resistor? I'm assuming the latter and the reason you need one for a GPIO input port is that nobody is driving that signal to a known voltage when the button isn't pressed - it is floating. So in case of an active high signal, you need a pull-down of 10k or so on the GPIO side. Or alternatively enable pull-downs in the GPIO peripheral if it supports it.